# Angular 6: Sharing component between feature modules doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-components, angular-module

I created 2 feature modules (`PagesSharedModule` & `HomeModule`).
Now I'm trying to use an exported component from `PagesSharedModule` inside the template of a component from `HomeModule` & I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'app-main-menu' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-main-menu' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-main-menu' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR
->]<app-main-menu></app-main-menu>"): ng:///HomeModule/HomeComponent.html@0:0 Error: Template parse errors: 'app-main-menu' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-main-menu' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-main-menu' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR
->]<app-main-menu></app-main-menu>"): ng:///HomeModule/HomeComponent.html@0:0
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:215)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14687)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:22687)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:22674)
    at compiler.js:22617
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:22617)
    at compiler.js:22527
    at Object.then (compiler.js:206)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:22526)
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:215)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14687)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:22687)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:22674)
    at compiler.js:22617
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:22617)
    at compiler.js:22527
    at Object.then (compiler.js:206)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:22526)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3751)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
```

If it makes any difference, `HomeModule` is a routed lazy-loaded module.

My code:

*src/app/pages/pages-shared/pages-shared.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MainMenuComponent } from './main-menu/main-menu.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MainMenuComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    MainMenuComponent
  ]
})

export class PagesSharedModule { }
```

*src/app/pages/pages-shared/main-menu/main-menu.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-menu',
  templateUrl: './main-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-menu.component.scss']
})
export class MainMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

*src/app/pages/home/home.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { PagesSharedModule } from 'src/app/pages/pages-shared/pages-shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    PagesSharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ]
})

export class HomeModule { }
```

*src/app/pages/home/home.component.html*

```
<app-main-menu></app-main-menu>
```

*src/app/pages/pages-routing.module.ts*

```
...
{
  path: '',
  component: PagesComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
    },
    {
      path: 'about',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      loadChildren: './content/content.module#ContentModule'
    },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
  ]
},
...
```

*src/app/pages/home/home-routing.module.ts*

```
{
  path: '',
  pathMatch: 'full',
  component: HomeComponent
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I copied you code in stackblitz project. It's working. Check this url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6enbz

Comment: Please include the whole error message because it tells what is actually wrong in your code. And as it was mentioned above your code should work so that i think you didn't mention something

Comment: @Houssem Romdhani, I went over your code & the only thing that seems to be different than what I did is that in my case the feature modules are lazy loaded using a routing module (not included above). For me it still doesn't work for some unknown reason...

Comment: @yurzui, I updated my question with the full error message.

Comment: @Pini, please provide us HomeRoutingModule code.

Comment: @Houssem Romdhani, I added the routing configurations.

Comment: Import pages-routing module in PagesSharedModule

Comment: @Houssem Romdhani, Still the same error. BTW: I'm currently importing `PagesSharedModule` into `HomeModule`, but I also tried to import it on `PagesModule` & `HomeRoutingModule` as well & got the same result.

Comment: So far, the only thing that removes the error & loads the view correctly, is importing the MainMenuComponent directly on HomeModule & adding to the declarations array. But obviously, that shouldn't be the way to do that with shared modules...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Unbelievable!!!
I stopped the angular CLI & served again & now it's all working perfectly without any change in the code.
Leaving this note here just in case anyone else is facing the same issue...